# Custom serializer java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-restcontroller

I put jsonignore all over my entity account, and a custom serializer on the Friend field.

now that I want to recover an account via  controller no more worries, however as soon as I try to recover it in service with the id or other I have the following error:

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

Entity:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int account_id;


    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    private boolean active;
    private String avatar;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ludo",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_account"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_boardGame"))
    private List<Boardgame> boardgameList;


    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    List<Friends> FriendsList;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_country_Id",nullable = true,referencedColumnName = "country_id")
    private Country country;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_language_Id",nullable = true,referencedColumnName = "language_id")
    private Language language;

    @Column(updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
}
```

Serializer:

```
public class FriendsSerializer extends StdSerializer<Friends> {

    public FriendsSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public FriendsSerializer(Class<Friends> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Friends friends, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("account_id", friends.getFriend().getAccount_id());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("username", friends.getFriend().getUsername());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("createdAt", String.valueOf(friends.getCreatedAt()));
        jsonGenerator.writeBooleanField("active", friends.isActive());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("avatar",friends.getFriend().getAvatar());
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("country");
        jsonGenerator.writeObject(friends.getFriend().getCountry());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

AccountService:

```
@Override
    public ApiResponse getFriendNoConfirmation(Account account) {
        if(account != null && account.getAccount_id() != 0){
           // List<Friends> listIdAccount = this.friendRepository.getFriendsNoConfirmation(account.getAccount_id());
            List<Integer> listIdAccount = this.friendRepository.getFriendsNoConfirmation(account.getAccount_id());
            if(listIdAccount != null){
               List<Account> listAccount = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int idAccount: listIdAccount){
                    System.out.println(idAccount);
                    Account friendAccount =  this.getAcountById(idAccount);
                    System.out.println(friendAccount);
                    listAccount.add(friendAccount);
                }
                return new ApiResponse(true, listIdAccount,BASE_CODE + "friendListNoConfirm.success");
            }else{
                return new ApiResponse(true, null,BASE_CODE + "friendListNoConfirm.error");
            }
        }else{
            return new ApiResponse(true, null,BASE_CODE + "friendListNoConfirm.error");

        }
    }

 @Override
    public Account getAcountById(Integer id){
        return this.accountRepository.getAccountById(id);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code from your controller & other relevant classes?

Comment: My guess: when an account is serialized, its board games are serialized. For each board games the account is serialized, which in turn causes board games to be serialized, which causes accounts to be serialized, ... This is the main reason why you shouldn't return entities directly from your REST endpoints but DTOs instead. In those DTOs you can remove the many-to-many relation that is causing the StackOverflowError.

Comment: @RobSpoor thank you for this advice but is there a way to fix it?

otherwise I have to recover my identifiers and redo a request to recover my accounts...?

Comment: Where is the stackoverflow exactly happening? All possible problematic fields are marked as `JsonIgnore`, so i don't think the problem is in the serialization. Perhaps you have an infinite loop between `Account` and `Friends` (mutual friends)? Please show more relevant lines of the stacktrace, and perhaps the source code of the `Friends` class.

Comment: @slindenau, yes I had an infinite loop - but I fixed the problem thanks for your help
How can I put that my problem is solved on this post?

Comment: @OrelM you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Please be specific in where the error was, and how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the mapped by and to get my objects I make queries by joining the tables